# Web proxy authentication over ISP

Tags: c#, authentication, network-programming

My ISP started to require authentication through a web page, the first time I get connected in.

I'd like to create a program to check my network state and tell me if I am already authenticated or not. If not, I want it to auto-connect over that login form (or any other more acurate way).

Using C#, I tried to open a new WebRequest and navigate, but the Respose state is 200 because the I got redirected to that login page when I am not connected.

Any ideas on how to do it?
Examples in C# or Java would be very nice!

**Update:**
Code that is being used to test for a 3xx response status

```
        HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.com.br");
        webReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        HttpWebResponse webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            Console.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

in the webResp object the status code is always 200.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`AllowAutoRedirect` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect) to false, then check for a 3xx status code.

Comment: Tried to change this option and send the web request again, but returns 200 in any way...It's weird. Could be some router configuration?

Comment: What is the response body? Compare the requests in Fiddler.

Comment: On fiddler the return is 302 Moved (as expected) but in code it still returning 200. Please take a look into my code to see if its wrong (updated in the main question above).

Comment: You're probably missing headers that it wants.

Comment: What kind of headers? Request or response headers? Could you be more specific please? Thanks!

Comment: @Andrey: Request headers.  Response headers are the headers it sends you, so you can't be missing them.

Comment: I've figured out that the User-Agent request header was missing in my C# Web Request. Now it's working, Thanks for the advice.